# jq add file contents into json and update

Tags: json, jq

I'm trying to use take a JSON object from a REST API `GET` call, then add the contents of a raw file (.md file in this case) into it using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), before updating the same object using a `PUT` call.

I'm using the following to GET the file and write it locally:

`curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD 'https://example.com/myfile.json' | cat > ./test.json`

The format of the JSON file is as follows:

```
{
  "content" : "My JSON content",
  "owner":...
}
```

I'd like to add the content of the raw file into `content`, so the result is as follows:

```
{
  "content" : "My markdown file contents.\n\nMy JSON content",
  "owner":...
}
```

and then update the original JSON using a `PUT` call:

`curl -u USERNAME:PASSWORD -d @./test.json -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT 'https://example.com/myfile.json'`

I'm wondering **how I can add the file content into my `JSON` file like that using jq**, if it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to a simple jq solution here is to read the raw text file using 'jq -R -s', and to read the JSON using one of the options in the --arg family.  Here, I'll use `--argfile` for simplicity and robustness across jq versions, but please note that the documentation says it is deprecated.

With the following jq program in a file, say program.jq:

```
. as $file
| $json
| (.content = $file + "\n" + .content)
```

and the following text in the file `contents.txt`:

```
Line 1 of contents.txt;
line 2.
```

and the following JSON in curl.json:

```
{
  "content": "My JSON content",
  "owner": "etc"
}
```

the invocation:

```
jq -R -s --argfile json curl.json -f program.jq contents.txt
```

produces:

```
{
  "content": "Line 1 of contents.txt;\nline 2.\n\nMy JSON content",
  "owner": "etc"
}
```

If using bash, instead of putting the curl output into a file, you could use: --argfile json <(curl ....)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer peak, it works perfectly :)

Comment: I piped the output into a file using
`jq -R -s --argfile json curl.json -f program.jq contents.txt > newfile.json`